# `` and '' quotes not working in Latex and csquotes not working either

Tags: fonts, incompatibility, csquotes, quotation

I just wanted to share that I solved this problem. Using `\usepackage{palatino}` will block `\usepackage{csquotes}` and it it will also mess up your backtick and apostrophe quotes (otherwise known as double quotes and single quotes) so they will not be curly.

To get curly quotes, so that you your quotation marks to not display backwards, remove the `Palatino` package.

[image]

This is after removing `palatino` and using the following code:
[image]

````
\usepackage [autostyle,  english = american]{csquotes}
\MakeOuterQuote{"}```
````

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: What is your problem? Ca you provide an example of small, but complete document with your problem. BTW, If you solve some problem and like to share your solution, than please first write question, which show it and to it write an answer with your solution. Now your question is unclear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. I *think* you're saying that the Palatino font doesn't work properly with the `csquotes` package, or maybe vice versa. If that's your claim, it's simply false. Your view may be related to the fact that you don't seem to like the way that opening anc closing single and double quotes look like when the Palatino text font is in use. You are, of course, entitled to your own views. However, you are not entitled to your own facts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not as it stands a question.